# how can i get core and reduct set in rough set R?

Tags: r, feature-selection

I'm using quickreduct in rough set R package, and i need the reduct set and the core.
how can i get the core and the reduct set?

```
   data(RoughSetData)
   dataset<-RoughSetData$wine.dt

   set.seed(5)
   dt.Shuffled <- dataset[sample(nrow(dataset)),]

   idx<-round(0.8*nrow(dt.Shuffled))
   wine.tra<-SF.asDecisionTable(dt.Shuffled[1:idx,], decision.attr = 14, 
   indx.nominal = 14)
   wine.tst<-SF.asDecisionTable(dt.Shuffled[(idx+1):nrow(dt.Shuffled), -
   ncol(dt.Shuffled)])

   reduct <-FS.feature.subset.computation(d.tra, method= "quickreduct.frst")
   print(reduct)
```